# Get Sum Of Columns Values Filtered Based On Another Columns Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet that basicly have several hundred rows that look like this

```
|01-Jan-16 (Fri) | Work | 0 |   0 | 3 | 0 | 9 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
```

I have been trying to generate a query that will calculate the total of each of the columns during any given quarter. So it will essentially select all the dates for month 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, 10-12 and calculates the total of value in all the 8 columns.

I have tried sumsif, and sumproduct but I can't get it to work, I am currently playing around with

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=1) * (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=2) * (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=3) * ('2016'!$C4:$C999) )

=SUMIFS('2016'!C4:C999, '2016'!A4:A999, "<=3", '2016'!A4:A999, ">=1")

=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)>=1)*(MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)<=3)*('2016'!B4:B999))
```

Comment: The two Sumproduct formulas should work. What do they return? Are the dates in column A really dates or text? If text, then it won't work. The Sumifs can't work because you are not extracting the month from column A.

Answer (score 0):

The date field is not a date value but a string so that is what is causing the problem. To get it to work you will need to pull out the date value for the match. I tested this with data created based off your example and it worked.

=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A5,1,9)))<=3)*(C2:J5))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=1) * (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=2) * (MONTH('2016'!$A4:$A999)=3) * ('2016'!$C4:$C999) )
```